# PL/SQL toolkit web application error when compiling procedure

Tags: plsql, package, procedure, toolkit

I am trying to develop web application based on tutorial example. I have created procedure cilveki_list which has many parameters. When I compile this code I get two errors:

```
1)PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2)PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

First error refers to line 'c_kods in varchar2 default null'
and the second one to line '    if p_action = 'INSERT' then'.

Proedure behaviour depends on the parameter 'p_action', if it is set to 'INSERT', then insertion is perfomed, if it is set to 'UPDATE', then table update is performed.

But what is wrong with porcedue, why I get those errors, when I try to compile it?

```
create or replace package PACKAGE2 is
procedure cilveki_list(
c_vards in char default null,
c_uzvards in char default null,
c_dzimsanas_gads in number default null,
c_kods in varchar2 default null,
p_action in varchar2 default 'DISPLAY');
end PACKAGE2;
/

create or replace package body PACKAGE2 is

procedure cilveki_list(
c_vards in char default null,
c_uzvards in char default null,
c_dzimsanas_gads in number default null,
c_kods in varchar2 default null,
p_action in varchar2 default 'DISPLAY')
is
l_count number := 0;
begin
if p_action = 'INSERT' then
insert into CILVEKI
values ('',c_vards,c_uzvards,c_dzimsanas_gads,c_kods);
commit;

elsif p_action = 'UPDATE' then  
    UPDATE CILVEKI 
        set VARDS = c_vards,    
            UZVARDS = c_uzvards,
            DZIMSANAS_GADS = c_dzimsanas_gads
        WHERE   PERS_KODS =  c_kods;
        commit;
    end if;

htp.htmlOpen;
htp.bodyOpen;
htp.tableOpen;
htp.tableRowOpen;
htp.tableHeader('VARDS');
htp.tableHeader('UZVARDS');
htp.tableHeader('DZIMSANAS_GADS');
htp.tableHeader('PERS_KODS');
htp.tableRowClose;

for c1 in (select VARDS, UZVARDS, DZIMSANAS_GADS,PERS_KODS
             from CILVEKI
            order by UZVARDS) loop
    htp.tableRowOpen;
    htp.tableData( 
        htf.anchor( 
          curl => 'cilveki_modify?p_action=UPDATE&p_ticker=' || c1.VARDS,
          ctext => c1.VARDS) );
    htp.tableData( c1.UZVARDS );
    htp.tableData( c1.DZIMSANAS_GADS );
    htp.tableData( c1.PERS_KODS );
    htp.tableRowClose;
    l_count := l_count + 1;
end loop;

htp.tableClose;
htp.p( l_count || ' rows found');
htp.anchor( curl => 'cilveki_modify?p_action=INSERT', 
            ctext => 'Create New' );
htp.bodyClose;
htp.htmlClose;
end cilveki_list;
end PACKAGE2;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE CILVEKI 
set VARDS = c_vards,    
    UZVARDS = c_uzvards,
    DZIMSANAS_GADS = c_dzimsanas_gads,
WHERE PERS_KODS =  c_kods
commit;
```

4th line above appears to be invalid. There shouldn't be a comma at the end of the line. Please remove the comma and re-compile the code.

Comment: Thanks for repply, I modifyed my code and also question. Now I am getting  other error

Comment: Modifyed code again, now Iam getting 'Error(1,14): PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'PACKAGE2' without its specification'

Comment: Is the package spec in valid state? Or, is it even created?

Comment: Thank you, got solution, there was sintax mistake